# column name for display in case

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

```
    SELECT favorite_id,MO,name,image_id,case image_id 
                    when 0 then (select image_path as image_path from images where image_id in (select default_image from registration where reg_id=9))
                    else (select image_path as image_path from images where image_id=b.image_id and active=1)
                    end
    FROM buddies b where reg_id=9
```

in this select:

```
   select image_path as image_path
```

i need to name the column name but because the select in the case the display name of the column is not appearing when running the query...

how can i name this column for display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the column alias after the case statement:

```
 SELECT 
     favorite_id,
     MO,
     name,
     image_id,
     case image_id 
         when 0 then (select image_path from images where image_id in (select 
         default_image from registration where reg_id=9))
         else (select image_path from images where image_id=b.image_id
         and active=1)
     end as alias_name_here
  FROM buddies b where reg_id=9
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5562d4/1